# Is there an ODBC driver for SQLCipher?

Tags: c++, odbc, sqlcipher

I'm evaluating an API to manipulating [sqlcipher](https://github.com/sqlcipher/sqlcipher) in C++. ODBC seems like a standard way to so.

Does anyone have experience on integration sqlcipher with [sqlite ODBC](http://www.ch-werner.de/sqliteodbc/)? How could I achieve this?

---

SQLite ODBC files:

```
$ ls -1 /cygdrive/c/Program\ Files\ \(x86\)/SQLite\ ODBC\ Driver/
adddsn.exe
addsysdsn.exe
inst.exe
instq.exe
license.terms
license.txt
README
readme.txt
remdsn.exe
remsysdsn.exe
sqlite3.exe
sqlite3_mod_blobtoxy.dll
sqlite3_mod_csvtable.dll
sqlite3_mod_extfunc.dll
sqlite3_mod_fts3.dll
sqlite3_mod_impexp.dll
sqlite3_mod_rtree.dll
sqlite3_mod_zipfile.dll
sqlite3odbc.dll
sqlite3odbcnw.dll
uninst.exe
Uninstall.exe
uninstq.exe
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We don't have first hand experience working with it, but the dynamic link variant's which need a provided sqlite3.dll (e.g. sqliteodbc_dl.exe,sqliteodbc_w64_dl.exe) might work if you were to swap in the SQLCipher dll in place of standard SQLite library.

Comment: I added the files under the SQLite ODBC install directory. Don't know which file I should replace.

Comment: just saw the alternative solution, will have a try.